# Load HtmlDocument from html with specific symbols (<, >)

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm creating `HtmlDocument` and using `LoadHtml(string)`. My input html string sometimes contains symbols `<` and `>` in it. So html parses incorrectly, for example:

My html is
`<p>Value < 20 A B C</p>`

And my document OutputHtml in this case is
`<p>Value < 20="" a="" b=""></p>`

Maybe there are some flags I have to set in HtmlDocument, but I didn't find anything helpful.

**P.S.** `HtmlNode` has the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you able to fix the HTML instead? The `<` should be `&lt;`. I know HTML is looser than XML, but I think that's still basically invalid HTML. (Just because it renders in browsers doesn't make it valid...)

Comment: I get html string from third-party source.  Maybe I can replace `<`, `>` symbols in this string with valid code and then call function, but how can I do it without replacing tags?

Comment: It sounds like you want to run HtmlTidy on it first - see http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ (Or some equivalent.)

Comment: Yes. That's a bug in HAP. Unlikely to be a setting, since that behaviour is always wrong. HtmlTidy looks to be your best bet.

Comment: @Alohci - it's not really a bug. The HTML specification does not say anything about how to render invalid HTML. Browser do it their own way which tends to be seen as "standard".

Comment: @SimonMourier - The HTML5 spec says a great deal on how to *parse* invalid HTML. In fact, it is thorough enough to cover any sequence of bytes. In this case, it's covered by the [tag open state of the tokenizer (anything else case)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#tag-open-state) which says that if the character following the `<` is a space, the angle bracket is just a less-than sign, and not the start of a tag.

Comment: @Alohci - oh, I should have said the "HTML 3 specification". Html Agility Pack is more than 10 years old. That does not mean it could not be changed though.

Comment: It is actually valid HTML 2, 3.2 and 4.x (since a `<` is allowed as character data if it is followed by a space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve the problem is to change the caharacter `<` in `&lt` (There is no need to change the character `>`)

To know when the the character `<` is of tag, and when it 'smaller than' you can ask with `if`
Here the code:

```
public static string CreateCorrectHtmlDoc(string htmlDoc)
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<int> index = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                //look for '<' 
                while ((i = htmlDoc.IndexOf("<", i)) != -1)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    //regex to find '<' that is no tag
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(htmlDoc[i].ToString(), "\\d|-") || Regex.IsMatch(htmlDoc[i].ToString(), "[^a-zA-Z!]") && Regex.IsMatch(htmlDoc[i + 1].ToString(), "\\d\\s|-|\\d"))
                    {
                        htmlDoc = htmlDoc.Substring(0, i - 1) + "&lt" + htmlDoc.Substring(i + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Log.Insert("Error: CreateCorrectHtmlDoc");
                return "";
            }
            return htmlDoc;
        }
```

I'm using it, and it is working perfect

Comment: @ChruS, You can change the Regex: instesd \\d put \\s\\d, I changed the code

Comment: Yes this works fine! But what if we have `<20` without space?